# Конфликт pkgconf-0.8.7_2 и pkg-config-0.25_1

Tags: ntfs, freebsd

Здравствуйте!

На системе (`freebsd8.2`) установлен сайт (`apache2.2, php5.2, mysql5.1`). При попытке устновить `fusefs-ntfs` (для чтения/записи на `ntfs`) выдается сообщение о конфликте`pkgconf-0.8.7_2` и `pkg-config-0.25_1`. При попытке удалить `pkg-config-0.25_1` система говорит что от этого пакета зависят другие (большинство из них `php52` расширения) и пакет не может быть удален. Подскажите, что делать, чтобы и сайт не упал и с `ntfs` работать можно было?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

devel/pkg-config заменен на devel/pkgconf.

Для portmaster выполнить:

```
# portmaster -o devel/pkgconf devel/pkg-config
```

, для portupgrade выполнить:

```
# portupgrade -fo devel/pkgconf pkg-config-\*
```

, pkgng:

```
# pkg set -o devel/pkg-config:devel/pkgconf# pkg install -f devel/pkgconf
```